# EF 6 with a dnx project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, dnx, project.json

I have a new ASP.net 5 dnx class library I am using for entity framework.  I need to target EF 6 because some features I need are not in EF 7.

First the EF tools (like enable-migration) were not there.  I added an old style class library and installed EF 6 and now the commands are there.

When I run enable migrations I get this error:

> PM> Enable-Migrations
>
> Exception calling "SetData" with "2" argument(s): "Type 
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject'
>   in assembly  'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation,
>   Version=14.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not  marked as serializable." At
>   D:\Projects\Rebus\FMS\Code\Current\FMSSupport\FMSSupport\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:720
>   char:5
>   +     $domain.SetData('startUpProject', $startUpProject)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SerializationException   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project
>   project, Int32 shellVersion)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebProject(Project
>   project)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String
>   configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.FindContextToEnable(String
>   contextTypeName)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tried different options for enable-migration such as specifying a startup project or the contextTypeName.

Any ideas?

Comment: I got this with a normal ASP.NET project...

Comment: Hehe, 'start up' caught my eye. I set web project as startup project, and then it worked :D

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I wanted ComplexType support which EFCore doesn't currently support. ATM I'm looking at having to manually unwind the complextypes in order to use EFCore :(

Comment: @Raskolnikov This question is not really useful. DNX is dead. You should upgrade to the release version of ASP.NET Core with the .NET Core CLI. A lot has changed about the project format which makes answers to this question very irrelevant to anything since the tooling no longer exists and you couldn’t reproduce anything.

Comment: Same issue on .Net Core 1.0

Comment: @Raskolnikov Then please create a new question instead. This question is not helpful in its current state and difficult to salvage.

Comment: Did you follow this guideline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6 ? Did you create a parameter less constructor? And all other requirements outlined here? It is useless to create ASP.NET Core with EF6 as it will not run on non windows platform anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Following this [recommendation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html#overview), EF6 data projects should use the existing .NET Framework class library csproj type.

Even after following the recommendations, I was still getting the same error. Unloading your ASP.NET Core project(s) and then invoking the `Enable-Migrations` command on the appropriate csproj should allow the command to execute. You can unload a project by right-clicking on the .NET Core project and choosing the 'Unload Project' option. It should also be noted that the Package Manager Console window has a 'Default project:' drop-down selection. You should choose the project with your DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

It's because ASP.NET Core introduced a new project type/configuration system (see [package.config vs project.json](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Converting-a-csproj-from-package.config-to-project.json)) and the old EF tools don't know how to work with the newer system (project.json). It would probably be easiest to create a new project and port your code into it if you want to go back to EF6.

Interestingly (well, disappointingly actually) they're backtracking on project.json see:
http://xoofx.com/blog/2016/05/11/goodbye-project-json/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Just setting the start project from ASP.NET Core to my .NET Framework Lib does the trick for me =) Now i can do EF6 migrations as usual "Add-Migration" command...

P.S. Sorry for my eng.